# How to see if a constant/TypeNode has been defined during a compile time macro?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible to check if a global constant (e.g. a TypeNode of Class, Struct, Module) has been defined by using a macro?

```
{% if defined?(::My_Class) %}
  puts "My_Class has been defined."
{% end %}
```

I know it's possible to get use `TypeNode#has_constant?`, but the question has to do whether or not a constant has been defined in the global namespace.

(The reason I asked is because during development and refactoring, I found this would be a convenient placeholder for a few circumstances until I can get the rest of the codebase re-written.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top level scope, the macro variable `@type` refers to the program. You can use `@type.has_constant?(:Foo)` to determine if a top level constant `Foo` is defined.

Comment: For a Path like `Foo::Bar`, would it then be `@type.has_constant?(:Foo) && Foo.has_constant?(:Bar)`?

Comment: Cool. Thanks again for this answer. I would have never had thought of using `@type` at the top level. How did that come to you? Naturally or by studying the beautiful Crystal source code?

Comment: I've asked the same question a few months ago on Gitter. ;)

Comment: Hahah... Thanks. That made me feel better.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a macro that simulates that functionality.
Use [TypeNode#resolve?](http://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.24.1/crystal/macros/path#resolve?:ASTNode%7CNilLiteral-instance-method) to check if the constant has been defined and then conditionally insert the code you want to execute:

```
macro if_defined(path, &blok)
  {% if path.resolve? %}
    {{blok.body}}
  {% else %}
    puts "Not defined: {{path.id}} "
  {% end %}
end # === macro if_defined

if_defined(Kemal::Session::My_Constant) do
  Kemal.listen
end
```